# allow other applications [3rd party] to access my asp.net website, user authentication

Tags: asp.net

I have a website which supports many kind of users based on their roles.
That is Sales,Customers etc.
I want to make my website to be accessible form other applications.
Like if any application want to fetch or send data to my application i should be able to grant them secure accessibility.
Please let me know how should i go about it to get the authentication part done.
Thanks in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "accessible form[sic] other applications" in a little more detail. Implementing OAuth will allow you to use federated authentication to assert a user's identity, but how you use that identity to authorize access to your application depends of the functionality you want to expose.

Comment: sorry i have updated my question. Hope you can understand it clearly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is fairly broad so I'm afraid I can only offer general guidance. The common approach to this is to expose your functionality as an API secured by OAuth. Users must authenticate with your application to get a bearer-token that they can then provide along with calls to your API to identify themselves and authorize the request.

If you are usinging ASP.Net I would suggest looking at the [Authentication and Authorization in Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security).